# How to install gettext's msgfmt from source?

Tags: linux, git, compile, gettext

I want to compile `git` which fails due to `/bin/sh: msgfmt: command not found` which is provided by `gettext`. I'm compiling on a system (Synology DSM 6.1) which has no package manager which easily provides a `gettext` package out-of-the-box, so I need to get the `gettext` build process to create `msgfmt` (with default `configure` options it's no `find`able in the installation prefix after `./configure --prefix=... && make && make install`), but I don't find any `configure` option of `gettext` to include creation of `msgfmt` in the build result nor any `configure` option of `git` to skip the part which needs `msgfmt`.

I'm now using `gettext` 0.19.8.1 and `git` 2.11.1, but am also happy for solutions which require other newer or older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msgfmt` can be installed by running `./configure && make && make install` in the `gettext-tools` directory under the `gettext` source root.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm compiling on a system (Synology DSM 6.1) which has no package manager which easily provides a gettext package out-of-the-box, so I need to get the gettext build process to create msgfmt

No. If you want Git on Synology, you have to install Git, from [vendor's packages](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/app_packages/all_app) or [community packages](https://synocommunity.com/packages). It can be [pure Git](https://synocommunity.com/package/git) (with 100% future headaches around "server", "web-frontend"), [Git Server](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/app_packages/Git) of full-ALM tool [GitLab](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/app_packages/Docker-GitLab)

Comment: Please specify _why_ my approach above won't work. I don't see a reason why I shouldn't be able to compile git.